# differential equation of first order - omitting absolute value operator

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, absolute-value, cauchy-problem

i have the equation:
$$y'+2y\:=1$$

and i solve it the regular way for first order differential equation:
$$y'\:=1-2y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1-2y$$
$$\int \:\frac{1}{1-2y}dy=\int \:1dx$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\int \:-\frac{2}{1-2y}dy=\int \:1dx$$
and using the integral formula:
[image]
$$-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\left|1-2y\right|\right)=x+\ln\left(c\right)$$
Why [Symbolab](https://he.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cleft%7C1-2y%5Cright%7C%3Dx) omits the absolute value operator and writes:
[image]

Comment: When you take the exponential of of both sides, you have $$|\pm e^{-2(x+c)}| = e^{-2(x+c)}$$ Because of this, over the reals, the absolute value drops, that is, the exponential is always positive.

Comment: i.e, in the equation: $\left|y\right|=x^2$, you can also drop the absolute value operator ? Oh, think this is true.

Comment: Symbolab might take this solution over the complex numbers. Then the sign difference under the logarithm is a difference of $i\pi$ in the integration constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$\int\frac{1}{1-2y}dy=\int 1dx, \text{ or }-\int\frac{1}{2y-1}dy=\int1dx $$
one has
$$ -\frac12\ln|2y-1|=x+C $$
or
$$ \ln|2y-1|=-2x-2C$$
So
$$ 2y-1=\pm e^{-2C}e^{-2x}$$
Let $k=\pm e^{-2C}$. Then
$$ y=\frac12+\frac12ke^{-2x}. $$
Since $k$ absorbs the signs, it does not matter if you have absolute value for $2y-1$ or not.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'+2y\:=1$$
With integrating factor method:
$$(ye^{2x})'=e^{2x}$$
$$ye^{2x}=\dfrac 12 e^{2x}+K$$
$$\boxed {y(x)=\dfrac 12 +Ke^{-2x}}$$
Then we can rewrite this as:
$$\dfrac {2y-1}K=e^{-2x} \geq 0$$
$$\ln \left (\dfrac {2y-1}K\right )=-2x $$
It seems to me that the absolute value is needed.